# Smooth scroll UI draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm having a problem with jQuery UI draggable..

I with to scroll an element within a smaller parent element, so that it creates a kind of viewport.

However, I'm having an issue with the element being dragged as it's snapping to the edges of the port.

Been battling with this for a while now so could really use some help... please :)

Here is an example of the behaviour I'm trying to get : [LINK](http://blog.creonfx.com/examples/javascript/facebook-cropping-mootools.html)

Here is a jsFiddle : [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/AFV5T/)

and sample code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- CSS -->
<style type="text/css">
#port{
 width:50px; 
 height:100px;
 border:1px solid red;
 overflow:hidden;
}

#obj {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: lightpink;
}
</style>

<!-- Javascript -->
<script>
$(function () 
{
 $("#obj").draggable(
 {
  containment: "#port",
  scroll: false,
  axis: 'x'
 });
});
</script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="port">
 <div id="obj">
  <p>Drag me</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found 'a' solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464285/jquery-ui-draggable-constrain-inner-element-within-parent-when-inner-element-i), but not sure of it's elegance...

```
<div id="outer"> <!-- position: relative -->
    <div id="inner"> <!-- position: absolute -->   
        <img id="img_1" src="http://media02.hongkiat.com/nature-photography/red-planet.jpg" width="300" height="100" />
    </div>
</div>


$(function() 
{
    var img = $("#img_1").draggable(
        { 
            containment: '#inner',
            axis: 'x'
        }),
    h = img.height(),
    w = img.width(),
    outer = $('#outer'),
    oH = outer.height(),
    oW = outer.width(),
    iH = h + (h - oH),
    iW = w + (w - oW),
    iT = '-' + ((iH - oH)/2) + 'px',
    iL = '-' + ((iW - oW)/2) + 'px';

    $('#inner').css({ width: iW, height: iH, top: iT, left: iL });    
})
```

However, tried it out and it does exactly what I'm after. So failing anything better I will go with this. Here is a [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/L2Se4/1/) for you guys to try it out.

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
<div id="port">
     <div id="obj">
      <p>This is my new paragraph</p>
     </div>
</div>

$(function() {
$( "#obj" ).draggable();
});
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/3HVT5/

It works when you remove the `containment: "#port"` line in your original code.

Comment: :) Tried the fiddle link, it's still snapping the element, I'm after a smooth scroll from edge to edge...

Comment: Updated it. Tried it now.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/AFV5T/1/)**

Hope this is what you need, since you specified `axis:x` , it will move only in x axis

```
$(function () {
    $("#obj").draggable({

        scroll: false,
        axis: 'x',

    });
});
```

Comment: Cool, I had that but when I added the containment option (to bind the drag obj to the edges) it starts the snapping behaviour.

Comment: so what you want to do now

Comment: I may not have explained myself correctly, I need the smooth scroll, but for it to stop at the edges of the port (be contained to parent)...

Comment: what you mean by contained , you parent div is smaller than your child one

Comment: Yep, child bigger than parent, so child moves INSIDE parent. However, when you drag the child to the left (for example) it can continue PAST the parent edge to the left. So you start to see a white space on the left as the child moves past edge. What I need is get the child to stop scrolling when it meets left or right edge of parent, and not continue past leaving white space.

Hope that makes sense!?

Comment: I have added another answer check it out

Comment: Here is an example of what I'm after: http://blog.creonfx.com/examples/javascript/facebook-cropping-mootools.html

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/AFV5T/3/)**

I guess this is what you need

```
 $(function () {
    $("#obj").draggable({
        containment: 'parent',

        axis: 'x',
        drag: function (event, ui) {
            var p = ui.helper.position();
            $(this).stop().animate({
                right: p.right,
                left: p.left
            }, 400, 'linear');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Adding the containment to parent brings back the 'snapping' action. 

I'm after this bevaviour: http://blog.creonfx.com/examples/javascript/facebook-cropping-mootools.html

Comment: Try this I have edited the code or you can use other plugin http://wayfarerweb.com/jquery/plugins/animadrag/